# Delete nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to delete a nested object from a JavaScript object, with no success and have not been able to find the correct answer through searching previous posts.

Here is what I have been trying to do.

```
<code id='code'></code>

var myobj = {
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "albuterol ",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "albuterol  - fluticasone ",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "prednisone ",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "dexamethasone ",
                  "children": [],
                  "size": 1,
                  "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.4"
                }
              ],
              "size": 3,
              "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.3"
            }
          ],
          "size": 4,
          "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.2"
        }]}]} 

function deleteObject(myobj) {
    var x = delete myobj.colname
    return (myobj.name, myobj.children)
}

document.getElementById('code').innerText = JSON.stringify(deleteObject(myobj))
```

I want to delete the object `colname`. Am I missing something or is the code completely incorrect?

Comment: `myobj` does not have a property called `colname`

Comment: I am a beginner with JSON. I thought that children, name, size, and colname were objects inside of the JSON. is that incorrect?

Comment: Do you want to delete *every* `colname`? There are many

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete every colname. Is that impossible?

Comment: You will need to create a recursive funcion which goes deeper in your array if there is a children prop

Comment: Very little in coding is "impossible" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a recursive function to delete the property.

```js
var myobj = {
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "albuterol ",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "albuterol  - fluticasone ",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "prednisone ",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "dexamethasone ",
                  "children": [],
                  "size": 1,
                  "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.4"
                }
              ],
              "size": 3,
              "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.3"
            }
          ],
          "size": 4,
          "colname": "CONCEPT_NAME.2"
        }]}]} 

function deleteColnameRecursive(obj){
  delete obj.colname
  if(obj.children){
     for(var i=0;i<obj.children.length;i++)
         deleteColnameRecursive(obj.children[i]);
  }
}

deleteColnameRecursive(myobj);

console.log(myobj);
```

Answer (score -3):

MyObj does not directly have a property of colname.
MyObj has an array named Children.

To delete the proper attribute, select the proper object. For example `myObj.children[0].colname`