# search inside object of objects and replace value

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion

I want to loop through all objects values inside object and replace password value with *** Restricted ***  . I want to use recursive way tp loop over all this items

before i was targeting objects that include password value but was thinking that it can appear somewhere else inside the object entry .

this is what i tried

```
if (entry.requestBody) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(entry.requestBody)) {
      if (key.toLowerCase().includes("password")) {
        entry.requestBody[key] = "***Restricted***"
      }
    }
    if (entry.config._object) {
      for (const key of Object.keys(entry.config._object)) {
        if (key.toLowerCase().includes("password")) {
          entry.config._object[key] = "***Restricted***"
        }
      }
    }
}



{
  "requestBody": {
    "email": "ror@ror.com",
    "password": "asdasdsad"
  },
  "code": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "config": {
    "isJoi": true,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "\"email\" must be a valid email",
        "path": [
          "email"
        ],
        "type": "string.email",
        "context": {
          "value": "ror@ror.com",
          "key": "email",
          "label": "email"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_object": {
      "email": "ror@ror.com",
      "password": "asdasdsad"
    },
    "_meta": {
      "source": "body"
    }
  }
}
}




"requestBody": {
    "email": "ror@ror.com",
    "password": "***Restricted***"
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having writing a recursive function to do it?

Comment: Hello barmar , am really new to the field and i was advised by someone to use recursive function to solve it but . i don't know how . i was solving this by looping through entry.requestbody and entry._object  but someone told me that how i know that maybe in future i can find password in meta or somewhere else so he said use recursive i did search and read about it but didn"t understand how to solve it that way .

Comment: If this is beyond your capabilities, you need to find/hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suport barmar

Comment: Here's a question about deleting a property recursively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066668/delete-nested-javascript-object/51066896#51066896 It shouldn't be hard to change it to update the property.

Comment: Do you really need to use `key.toLowerCase().includes("password")` instead of just matching the property `password` exactly?

Comment: key.toLowerCase().includes("password") yes because the key can be newPassword or currentPassword and so on .so that"s why i use it and it was working fine until i knew that maybe also be included in meta or something else . so i will not make for loop for every object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `recursion`, how about using `regex` for a quick and dirty solution:

```
var bodyString = JSON.stringify(entry.requestBody);

var fixedBodyString = bodyString.replace(/"password":".*"/g, '"password":"***Restricted***"');

var body = JSON.parse(fixedBodyString );
```

Working example:
https://playcode.io/353673?tabs=script.js,preview,console